# Remove IF-ELSE conditional statements and Vectorization

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, vectorization

I need to use feval to evaluate a function on a vector of values. The function is defined by:

```
function v = s(x,y)
if y>=0.5
    if (-2*(x-3/4)+(y-1/2))<0
        v=-0.5;
    else
        v=1.5;
    end
else
    v=max( -0.5,min( 1.5,(x-3./4)/(y-1./2) ) );
end
end
```

The following solution does not work:

```
function v = s(x,y)
ind1=(y>=0.5); 
ind2=(-2*(x(ind1)-3/4)+(y(ind1)-1/2)<0);
ind3=(-2*(x(ind1)-3/4)+(y(ind1)-1/2)>=0);
v(ind2)=-0.5;
v(ind3)=1.5;
v(~ind1)=max( -0.5,min( 1.5,(x(~ind1)-3./4)/(y(~ind1)-1./2) ) );
end
```

Indeed, with:

```
p(1,:)=[2 3 4 5];
p(2,:)=[1 0 7 8];
hs=@s;
f=feval(hs, p(1,:), p(2,:));
```

I get f=

```
-0.500000000000000  -0.500000000000000  -0.500000000000000
```

instead of a 4-valued vector.

Comment: Don't you mean removing `IFs` rather than vectorization of them? Are those `x` and `y` vectors? Even so, your first approach looks like vectorized already.

Comment: Yes, I need to remove the if's to use vectorization. But the above solution does not work.

Comment: How about the below solution? What exactly is `huEx`? Looks like it could be the function `s`.

Comment: Sorry, it is a handle to s. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this logical indexing approach works for you -

```
function v = s(x,y)

cond1 = y>=0.5;
cond2 = (-2*(x-3/4)+(y-1/2))<0;

val = max( -0.5,min( 1.5,(x-3./4)./(y-1./2) ) );
v = -0.5.*(cond1&cond2) + 1.5.*(cond1&~cond2) + ~cond1.*val;

return;
```

Comment: There seem to be a little syntax problem: "Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values." You are sure it will work before I try to make it work ?

Comment: You are not working with nuclear codes I am hoping. That might hurt when trying out :) Yeah it should work, I tested with scalar values I think.

Comment: It is just a prototype, it it will only "virtually" blow up !

Comment: @Gonzague Fixed that! Should work now. Giving me `-0.5000    0.5303    1.5000   -0.5000` for your sample inputs.

Comment: @Gonzague Waiting for your update where you will put the correct values.

Comment: How do I insert code in comments ? I delete this comment after, sorry.

Comment: Why not edit your question with those outputs? You may give reference to my solution there.

Comment: @Gonzague Fixed! The issue was that I wasn't doing it element-wise across the function. Check it out!